# ResponseEntity returns null list of objects

Tags: spring, rest, api, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am able to consume an API who returns a json object. What I am trying to do is to get a list of objects instead. Below is my code for the same:

```
ResponseEntity<List<Entity>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(dataUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity,new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<Entity>>() {});
```

where Entity of an object of which I am expecting a list to be populated with data from json. But when I print it, all fields from Entity has null value set. What am I missing?

Thanks 
Sach

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with this

```
ResponseEntity<List<Entity>> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(dataUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Entity.class);
```

p.s. sorry don't have reputation for comment :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use `restTemplate.getForEntity`?

```
ResponseEntity<Entity[]> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(dataUrl, Entity[].class)
Entity[] entities = response.getBody();
```

The above case returns an object of type `Entity[]`, which is an array.

If you want to use the `List` interface, you will need to create a wrapper class.

The wrapper:

```
public class EntityList {
    private List<Entity> entities;

    public EntityList() {
        entities= new ArrayList<>();
    }

    // standard constructor and getter/setter
}
```

The `RestTemplate` call:

*Here you will use `restTemplate.getForObject`*

```
EntityList response = restTemplate.getForObject(dataUrl, EntityList.class);
List<Entity> entities = response.getEntities();
```

Even a simpler alternative is to use `List.class` as the return type of `getForObject`.

```
List<Entity> response= rest.getForObject(dataUrl, List.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Matheus. I might be using above solution as I have to pass headers int the request.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to give a correct answer due to a missing json example. Could you please provide a sample of the json that will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED

Below is the code change I did which was returning correct list of Entity objects.

```
ResponseEntity<Entity[]> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(dataUrl, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Entity[].class);
```

Even after making this change didnt really solved my issue. I also had to add

```
@JsonProperty("fieldName") on each field in Entity class which had to match Json properties.
```